# Transforming DataFrame (pivot)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do have problems transforming a DataFrame into a new structure.
After turning a pivot table into a DataFrame, my data looks like this:

```
          model      model1     model2
 time     color     
2001-01   blue       200,000    120,000
          red        100,000    100,000
          yellow     250,000    80,000
          white      100,000    100,000
2002-01   blue       140,000    150,000
          red        200,000    100,000
          yellow     400,000    200,000
          white      200,000    100,000
...
```

Now, this is what I want to turn it into:
time as the index and for each model's color a distinct column.

```
          model1_blue  model1_red  model1_yellow  model1_white  model2_blue ...
 time     
2001-01   200,000      100,000     250,000        100,000       120,000
2002-01   140,000      200,000     400,000        200,000       150,000
...
```

Now: How does this work :)? Thank you!

Comment: is `model` index or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that `model` is an index , if not you can simply convert it to be an index using

```
df.set_index('model' , inplace=True)
```

convert your model index to be a column instead

```
df_unstacked = df.unstack('model')


Out[28]:
        model1                     model2
model   blue    red     white   yellow  blue    red     white   yellow
time                                
2001-01 200,000 100,000 100,000 250,000 120,000 100,000 100,000 80,000
2002-01 140,000 200,000 200,000 400,000 150,000 100,000 100,000 200,000
```

Retrieve columns names for both levels

```
first_level_names = df_unstacked.columns.levels[0]
second_level_names = df_unstacked.columns.levels[1]
```

Create new columns names

```
new_columns = [ first+ '_' + second for first in first_level_names  for second in second_level_names ]
```

assign new column names to your data frame

```
df_unstacked.columns = new_columns

Out[33]:
        model1_blue model1_red  model1_white    model1_yellow   model2_blue model2_red  model2_white    model2_yellow
time                                
2001-01 200,000     100,000      100,000          250,000        120,000      100,000   100,000         80,000
2002-01 140,000     200,000      200,000          400,000        150,000      100,000   100,000         200,000
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `time` and `model color` are forming a hierarchical index (if they are not, you can create this index easily with `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`), the simplest solution would be to "unstack" that index:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [200, 120], 
        [201, 123], 
        [202, 124], 
        [203, 125] ,
        [204, 126] ,
        [205, 126] ,
        [205, 127], 
        [205, 127],         
    ], columns=["model1", "model2"])

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["2001-01", "2001-02"], ["blue", "red", "yellow", "white"]])
df
```

[image]

```
df.unstack()
```

[image]